# Spring Security - GrantedAuthority and role-based access

Tags: spring, security, roles, authority

I'm using a custom UserDetailService which works fine for authentication. The problem is that I can't use role-based constraints.

It's odd that I get the correct authorities from the Controller:

```
public ModelAndView getMembers(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication auth) 
{
   if(auth != null)
   {
      for (GrantedAuthority ga : auth.getAuthorities())
      {
         // works find and logs "ADMIN", btw. I'm using SimpleGrantedAuthority
         this.logger.debug("0{}", ga);
      }
   }
}
```

But with the configuration

```
http
   .csrf().disable()
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/Admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
   …
```

The user can't access pages at e.g. /Admin/Member.

Same goes for thymeleaf-security-tags, e.g.

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated() && hasRole('ADMIN')">Hello Admin!</div>
```

doesn't show "Hello Admin!" for users where the Controller logs authority "ADMIN".

I'm guess I'm missing something or using something wrong.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Did you try hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or use hasAuthority('ADMIN')

Comment: Thanks, hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') doesn't work but the hasAuthority('ADMIN')-approach works like a charm … in thymeleaf-security and in spring configuration. Does anyone knows how to set principal's roles in a custom UserDetailService.

Comment: Close this question and open a new one

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, you have to use `hasAuthority("ADMIN")`instead of `hasRole("ADMIN")`.

It's important to make the distinction between Granted Authorities and Roles. There is an article from Baeldung explaining it: [Granted Authority Versus Role in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-granted-authority-vs-role). From this article we can understand the difference:

GrantedAuthority

> In Spring Security, we can **think of each GrantedAuthority as an individual privilege**. Examples could include READ_AUTHORITY, WRITE_PRIVILEGE, or even CAN_EXECUTE_AS_ROOT. [...]
>
> When using a GrantedAuthority directly, such as through the use of an expression like hasAuthority(‘READ_AUTHORITY’), we are restricting access in a fine-grained manner.

Role as Authority

> Similarly, in Spring Security, we can **think of each Role as a coarse-grained GrantedAuthority that is represented as a String and prefixed with “ROLE“**. When using a Role directly, such as through an expression like hasRole(“ADMIN”), we are restricting access in a coarse-grained manner.